# How did Nadia Boulanger teach students?

Tags: theory, composition

What was the general method that Boulanger utilized when teaching composition students? Please be specific, what exercises did she use? What books did she prefer? etc.

Comment: Do you already have these points? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadia_Boulanger#The_pedagogue. It lists some typical sounding stuff like harmony, species counterpoint, sight singing, etc. As well as comments about aesthetics.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that page, I'm trying to go in deep so I can get some better techniques for teaching myself composition as I don't have money for lessons.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but probably you want to continue the research process. Some quick scanning at Google Books previews https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=nadia+boulanger and then try using "interlibrary loan" at a nearby public or university library if you have access. You may get some overview answers here, but probably better to do the reading yourself.

Comment: Do you know about Schoenberg's _Fundamentals of Composition_? Also, William Caplin's _Classical Form_ while not considered a composition book sure seems like one in disguise :-) Off topic, but maybe of interest.

Comment: Yes, I've read those two, I found them through the Art of Composing.com. Sorry, I don't mean to be all back and forth like this with your suggestions haha. I just discovered Mrs. Boulanger and the EAMA and am super stoked trying to learn everything about their ideas!